# Registration Form 500 | Server Error - Laravel/Tailwind CSS

Tags: php, forge, tailwind-css, laravel-7

When I submit the registration form (homepage) the data is passed to the database, however, I am getting back a server 500 error. I tried to tinker with the code without much luck. Any idea why this is occurring?

Tech stack - Laravel, Forge, TailwindCSS.

https://famijam.com/register

Registration Form

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="max-w-md w-full">
        <div>
            <h2 class="mt-6 text-center text-3xl leading-9 font-extrabold text-gray-900">
              Register
            </h2>
          </div>
          <form class="mt-8" action="/register/create" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="true" />
            <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
              <div>
                <input aria-label="Name" name="name" type='text' required class="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" placeholder="Full Name" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="-mt-px">
                <input aria-label="Email address" name="email" type="email" required class="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" placeholder="Email address" />
              </div>
              <div class="-mt-px">
                <input aria-label="Password" name="password" type="password" required class="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" placeholder="Password" />
              </div>
              <div class="-mt-px">
                <input aria-label="Password-confirm" name="password_confirmation" type="password" required class="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
              </div>
            <div class="mt-6">
              <button type="submit" class="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                <span class="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                  <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-indigo-500 group-hover:text-indigo-400 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 9V7a5 5 0 0110 0v2a2 2 0 012 2v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5a2 2 0 012-2zm8-2v2H7V7a3 3 0 016 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                  </svg>
                </span>
                Register
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    @endsection
```

RegisterController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(Request $request)
    {
        User::create($request->all());
        return redirect('/profile/index');

    }
}
```

Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@about')->name('about');

Route::get('/contact', 'ContactFormController@create');
Route::post('/contact', 'ContactFormController@store');

Route::post('/register/create', 'Auth\RegisterController@create')->name('register');

Route::get('/post/index', 'PostController@index');
Route::get('/post/create', 'PostController@create');
Route::get('/post/show', 'PostController@show');
Route::post('/post', 'PostController@store');

Route::get('/profile/index', 'ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
```

Server Log

```
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/forge/famijam.com/storage/framework/views/c6c98ba0103c54568a1f639919507c6dedd70bdc.php(68): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(41): include('/home/forge/fam...')
#2 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(57): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
#3 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Views/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(37): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#4 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Facade\\Ignition\\Views\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()
#5 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(122): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#6 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#7 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(62): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#8 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(34): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent()
#9 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(749): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct()
#10 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(721): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse()
#11 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse()
#12 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#13 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#14 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#15 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(76): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#16 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#17 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#18 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#19 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#20 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#21 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#23 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#25 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(683): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#27 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#28 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#29 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(613): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#30 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#31 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#32 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#33 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#34 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#35 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#36 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#37 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#38 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#39 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
#40 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(36): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#41 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#42 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#43 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#44 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#45 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#46 /home/forge/famijam.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#47 /home/forge/famijam.com/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#48 {main}
"}
```

Laravel Log

```
Did you mean this?
    storage:link {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\CommandNotFoundException(code: 0): Command \"storage\" is not defined.

Did you mean this?
    storage:link at /Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:644)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/vendor/symfony/console/Command/HelpCommand.php(70): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->find('storage')
#1 /Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\HelpCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#2 /Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(912): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(264): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\HelpCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(140): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 /Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel 2.php(130): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /Users/paolo/Documents/code/Famijam/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#8 {main}
"}
```

Profile.index.blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="max-w-md w-full">
      <div>
        <h2 class="mt-6 text-center text-3xl leading-9 font-extrabold text-gray-900">
          Sign in to your account
        </h2>
        <p class="mt-2 text-center text-sm leading-5 text-gray-600">
          Or
          <a href="/register" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:underline transition ease-in-out duration-150">
            Register
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <form class="mt-8" action="/login" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="true" />
        <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
          <div>
            <input aria-label="Email address" name="email" type="email" required class="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" placeholder="Email address" />
          </div>
          <div class="-mt-px">
            <input aria-label="Password" name="password" type="password" required class="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" placeholder="Password" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-6 flex items-center justify-between">
          <div class="flex items-center">
            <input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" />
            <label for="remember_me" class="ml-2 block text-sm leading-5 text-gray-900">
              Remember me
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="text-sm leading-5">
            <a href="#" class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:underline transition ease-in-out duration-150">
              Forgot your password?
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-6">
          <button type="submit" class="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
            <span class="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 flex items-center pl-3">
              <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-indigo-500 group-hover:text-indigo-400 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 9V7a5 5 0 0110 0v2a2 2 0 012 2v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5a2 2 0 012-2zm8-2v2H7V7a3 3 0 016 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </span>
            Sign in
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  @if (Auth::check())
      You are signed in.
    @else 
    You are not signed in.
  @endif

  <div class="mt-10 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl px-4 sm:mt-12 sm:px-6 md:mt-16 lg:mt-20 lg:px-8 xl:mt-28">
      <div class="sm:text-center lg:text-center">
        <h2 class="text-4xl tracking-tight leading-10 font-extrabold text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl sm:leading-none md:text-6xl">
          Dashboard </h2>
          <ul>
              @foreach ($posts as $post)
              <li>{{ $post->title }}</li>
              <li>{{ $post->body }}</li>
              @endforeach
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

ProfileController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Profile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('/profile.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $profile = \App\Profile::all();

        return view('profile.create', compact('profile'));
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min:5',
            'body' => 'required|max:10000'
            // Future 
            // Images, Gifs 
        ]);

        \App\Profile::create($data);

       return redirect()->back();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Profile  $profile
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Profile $profile)
    {
        return view('profile.index', compact('profile'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Profile  $profile
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Profile $profile)
    {
        return view('profile.edit', compact('profile'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Profile  $profile
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Profile $profile)
    {
        $profile->update($this->validatedData());

        return redirect('/profiles');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Profile  $profile
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Profile $profile)
    {
        $profile->delete();

        return redirect('/profiles');
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the server's error logs for more detail.

Comment: @JayBlanchard updated in the main post.

Comment: fyi, there should be no need to create a register route yourself, `Auth::routes();` handles all login/password/registration routes

Comment: @kerbholz I added the laravel log in the main post. I used TailwindCSS to create the forms and I think I may have broken the ```Auth::routes();```... Do you think I should just revert back to the original routes?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error? It's pointing to something in your view.

Comment: Is that the complete Laravel log? fyi, errors get appended to the end of the log. Not sure if your `Route::post('/register/create', ...` screws something up. I wouldn't revert anything just yet

Comment: Based on what you've posted it seems that a command, storage, is not defined. I don't see that command usage in the code that you've posted though.

Comment: @aynber sure, in my localhost I just got this error:  ```Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: posts (View: ``` and ``` $posts is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $posts }} with {{ $posts ?? '' }} Make variable optional``` its from a ```@foreach ($posts as $post) <li>{{$post->title}}</li>```

Comment: Okay, your error is coming from none of the code you've provided. The registration portion works fine, this error happens on the `profile/index` route. We can only guess that you're not passing `$posts` into the view.

Comment: @aynber I added the profile.index.blade in the original post.

Comment: Can you show also the controller 'ProfileController@index'?

Comment: @aynber sure, added to the original post.

Comment: Okay, there's your issue. Your index is just `return view('/profile.index');`. No `$posts`. Your index file is referencing `$posts`, so you'll have to decide where that's supposed to come from and pass it in. Or delete that section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there's your issue. Your index is just return view('/profile.index');. No $posts. Your index file is referencing $posts, so you'll have to decide where that's supposed to come from and pass it in. Or delete that section. – (Credit to) aynber